# Is there a way to interactively rotate the canvas in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm aware of the "rotate canvas tool" in Photoshop CS 5 (which shares a spot in the tool menu with the "grabber hand tool").

What I'm wondering is if there's a way you can perform that function interactively, like you can with the zoom tool. I mean the kind of thing where you hold some key or key combo down and click and drag.

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out. Just hold down the <kbd>R</kbd> key and click-and-drag inside the viewport.

Comment: I can't do so, yet.

Comment: it says that work only with openGL windows.. any ideas?